# How to fix intellij errors in spring xml config file?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, gradle

I have a problem:

[image]

XML-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd" >

    <bean id="spaceship" class="com.examples.spring.Cruiser">
        <constructor-arg ref="energyweapon" />
        <constructor-arg name="str" value="hello" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="energyweapon" class="com.examples.spring.PlasmaCannon" />

</beans>
```

Despite the IDEA error my project still successfully compiles and runs. Is there any fix?

Gradle installation:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.14
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2016-06-14 07:16:37 UTC
Revision:     cba5fea19f1e0c6a00cc904828a6ec4e11739abc

Groovy:       2.4.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          1.8.0_73 (Oracle Corporation 25.73-b02)
OS:           Windows 7 6.1 amd64
```

build.gradle:

```
group 'com.examples.spring'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.1.RELEASE'
}
```

Intellij IDEA:
IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.1.3

Comment: Links to image in drop-sites are strongly discouraged because 1) the text cannot be copy-and-pasted, and 2) the image URL for the code is liable to expire, rendering the question meaningless to future readers.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like for some reason IDEA is looking at an older `spring-beans.xsd` to validate your document. Using a `name` attribute in `<constructor-arg>` is [correct in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-ctor-arguments-resolution). I have a couple thoughts:

1. Ensure that IDEA has properly refreshed its list of dependencies from your Gradle file. In the Project tool window, under "External Libraries", is the version of Spring you're using listed there, and no other versions? If not, double-check that it's reading the Gradle file you think it is and try refreshing it. (I've not used Gradle, only Maven, but the Maven tab has a "refresh" button, so I'm assuming that it works similarly for Gradle.)
2. You could try adding a direct reference to the `spring-beans` dependency, although that shouldn't be needed.
3. If you can't get IDEA to look at the right file automatically, you can change your XSD path in the `xsi:schemalocation` from `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd` to `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd`. This should do it, though you'll probably need to update the version number when you update to a newer version of Spring. (I tend to use the specific version in general, just to force myself to go through every file when updating Spring, but there's probably not a good reason to force myself to do that, as it *should* work the way you're doing it.)

Answer (score 0):

From documentation xsd file :

The exact name of the argument in the constructor argument list.
Only needed to avoid ambiguities, e.g. in case of 2 arguments of
the exact same type. ***Note: This requires debug symbols to be
stored in the class file in order to introspect argument names!***

First part is telling this is not necessary attribute, you can just put value, spring will autowire it by order, and second part I am not sure what means, but it could be a reason why you see and error.